# to generate college time table using bipartite matching

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

I Have an assignment to implement using maximum bipartite matching i.e I want to generate a lecture time table for a week where the condition is i have 5 subjects and the classes commence 5 days in a week and each day there are four hours and each subject should be equally allocated i.e 4 hours. and no two subjects should have consecutive hours.

Can i implement this using Maximum Bipartite Matching?
I would like to use java.

And  should i be using multidimensional matrix?? for subjects, hours, and days.?

I want to take subjects and hours as the two subset of vertices.
Have five iterations indicating five days.

But how can I ensure that different subset of subjects get allocated in different iteration

Comment: You should also provide your effort in the problem, show us what you have tried till now? You do not get direct solutions on SO unless and until you have shown the needed research and effort for it. So if you have something in mind how you are going to do it then edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks more to be  a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). Good old Prolog fd-solver would not require more than 10 lines to solve this ;).